# Open executable jar from Unity UWP

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, executable-jar

I'm building a windows app using Unity3d and I want to include an executable `.jar` file which has to open on button click from the app. Is there any way to develop this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a direct way to do this. Pure UWP apps (which are generated by Unity) are sandboxed and compiled using .NET Native. As such they don't allow executing external code/process as that would pose security risk.

If you used an external Desktop Bridge app (which has full permissions) and communicated with it via app service (see [this documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/appconsult/desktop-bridge-the-migrate-phase-invoking-a-win32-process-from-a-uwp-app)), you could theoretically achieve this, but it sounds a bit too complex. Another alternative would be to publish your app as a classic Win32 game. It would still be possible to publish it on Microsoft Store, however it would be limited to desktop devices.